# Angular 2 function not running consistently

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angularfire2

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AF } from "../angularfire.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.less']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private afService: AF) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afService.checkUser();
  }

}
```

Function inside the service:

```
checkUser() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    } else {
      console.log("not logged in");
    }
  }
```

Basically the function redirects the user to the dashboard view if they are logged in.  It works great when the view (app-login) is accessed via another view, but if you were to access the view by typing in the url, the function doesn't perform the redirect and instead logs "not logged in".

Comment: I'm able to get it working with this workaround but it seems very hackish:  `setTimeout(() => this.afService.checkUser(), 300);`

Comment: withouth knowing what firebase.auth() does its hard to tell what is going on in the checkUser method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, as its mention in firebase documentation:  [can view it here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

> Note: currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

so that is explain your issue and also explain why your `setTimeout` solve that, because its return an observable.
second, by the syntax you wrote down above, I assume that you don't use `AngularFire2` service(just lack of description of your service) , so i will suggest you to use `AngularFire2` cause its more simple, and provide simple API to communicate with `angularfire-database`.
I can suggest the follow solution with `AngularFire2`:
Component:

```
//basically the same.
```

Service:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import 'rxjs/Rx' ;
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

constructor(public af: AngularFire){}
 checkUser() {
  this.af.auth.first().toPromise().then(user => {
   if (user) {
     this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
   } else {
     console.log("not logged in");
   }
  }
 });
```

Just adjust it to your code, and enjoy :)